# InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'GenreId'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this code. I've watched on other stack overflow posts, but nothing works for me. Do I miss something? I need to make some dropdowns for genre, publisher and author and I couldn't find anything which could help me. I tried viewbag because I found it in many places, but it's not working for me. I don't know if viewbag is for .net mvc core 3.1

Book Model

```
 public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int AvailableCopies { get; set; }

    public int TotalCopies { get; set; }

    public string GenreId { get; set; }

    public int PublisherId { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BorrowProcess> BorrowProcesses { get; set; }
}
```

Books Controller:

```
 //POST: Books/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create([Bind("BookId,Title,TotalCopies,AvailableCopies")] Book book)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(_genres, "GenreId", "Name");
            _bookService.AddBook(book);
            _bookService.Save();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(book);

    }
```

Create View:

```
@model LibraryApplication.Models.Book

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Book</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AvailableCopies"></label>
                <input asp-for="AvailableCopies" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AvailableCopies" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TotalCopies"></label>
                <input asp-for="TotalCopies" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TotalCopies" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @*<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="GenreId"></label>
                <select asp-for="GenreId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GenreId"></select>
            </div>*@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownList("GenreId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenreId)
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PublisherId"></label>
                <select asp-for="PublisherId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PublisherId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

I'm using MVC Core 3.1. What could be the problem?

Update:

```
public BooksController(BookService bookService, AuthorService authorService, GenreService genreService, PublisherService publisherService)
 {
 _bookService = bookService;
 _authorService = authorService; 
_genreService = genreService;
 _publisherService = publisherService;
 _genres = _genreService.GetGenres(); } 
// GET: Books 
public IActionResult Index(string SearchString) 
{ 
var books = _bookService.GetBooks();
 return View(books); 
} 
.....
```

Comment: What's the type of `_genres`?

Comment: And I don' t see a get action. Can only see a post one.

Comment: it's a list of type Genre which is another model

Comment: public BooksController(BookService bookService, AuthorService authorService, GenreService genreService, PublisherService publisherService)
        {
            _bookService = bookService;
            _authorService = authorService;
            _genreService = genreService;
            _publisherService = publisherService;
            _genres = _genreService.GetGenres();
        }
 

        // GET: Books
        public IActionResult Index(string SearchString)
        {
            var books = _bookService.GetBooks();
            return View(books);


        }

Comment: I have the get method, but I didn't think it's relevant. I'm new to it

Comment: This post needs details or clarity. There is no code to get  a create view. Only code to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix  DropDownList.  Try this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenreId, @ViewBag.GenreId, "Choose an option", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and you need one more action

```
     [HttpGet]
     public IActionResult   Create()
    {

            ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(_genres, "GenreId", "Name");
            
           var model = new Book();
        return View(model);

    }
```

Comment: If I'm trying to do this, it doesn't let me. 'Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type. An annonymous function or method group cannot be used as a constituent value of a dynamically bound operation'

Comment: Did you use the action  I added for you?

Comment: I went back to this : @Html.DropDownList("GenreId", null, new { @class = "form-control" }), but I added in the get method of create the viewbag. This solved the issue. Thank you!